# Is there a way to reference a certain class/interface/... by enclosing it with its namespace rather than a using directive "using namespace_name"?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, sap-dotnet-connector

Is there a way to reference a certain class/interface/... by enclosing it with its namespace rather than a using directive "using namespace_name" ?!

As, I'm working on a website, which uses SAP .NET connector. I already added a reference for connector ddl, and while referencing its namespace "using namespace_name", or set class namespace to another one rather than connector namespace,

I got error regarding connector classes with that error message "The type or namespace couldn't be found, are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?".

But while changing namespace name to connector namespace, everything is going well?!

```
// Set namespace to be IDestinationConfiguration interface namespace.
// Using this, everything is going well.
namespace SAP.Middleware.Connector
{
    public class ConnectorConfiguration : IDestinationConfiguration
    {
    }
}

// Using that way; it's not working, and got an error regarding IDestinationConfiguration even it belongs to refernced namespace.
using SAP.Middleware.Connector;

public class ConnectorConfiguration : IDestinationConfiguration
{
}
```

So, connector types forced me to set namespace of class to their namespace!

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: That code snippet is it "working" as I understand it. Could you paste the code that you think should work (and want to work) that is throwing the error? Possibly with the actual namespace rather than "namespace_name". ;-) One thing to try though would be if it works using a fully qualified name (eg `SAP.Middleware.Connector.IDestinationConfiguration` or something similar. This should be no different from having `using SAP.Middleware.Connector` but its a good test for more info... :)

Comment: There is one situation in which these would be different. If IDestinationConfiguation was declared in two namespaces both included with usings.

Comment: @James, it is only referenced by SAP.Middleware.Connector.

Comment: Hmm... That is very odd. My thinking was with @James so I'm out of ideas I'm afraid. If I think of anything later I'll come back though. :)

Comment: I've put a bit more in my answer - something to try - but just to prove that it's not duplicated in another namespace... if that fails then I am also stumped.

Comment: @Benjamin pointed this out @Ahmed: The second point is not within a namespace. Define your own namespace around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
public class ConnectorConfiguration: SAP.Middleware.Connection.IDestinationConfiguration
{

}
```

You can write all your code without usings if you like,  you just need to use the fully qualified namespace name for every class/interface where the using isn't used.

If you try this:

```
using SAPTEST = SAP.Middleware.Connection;
namespace TestNamespace 
{
   public class ConnectorConfiguration: SAPTEST.IDestinationConfiguration
   {
   }
}
```

If that works,  but it doesn't work if you remove SAPTEST,  then IDestinationConfiguration must be declared in another namespace too.

Comment: Not only IDestinationConfiguration interface, I should do this for each type of connector types, but if enclose the class with SAP.Middleware.Connector as a namespace name, everything is going well!

Comment: Yes, I know about fully qualified namespace, but this is not the problem.

Comment: Yes, because if you write your code in a given namespace then that namespace is 'automatically' in scope.  But you don't _need_ to do this.  You can use using, or you can explicitly fully qualify types.

Comment: Using a using directive isn't resolve the issues, I've to set namespace to the namespace of connector tyes rather than using directive.

Comment: Ah I see. Can you post the code that fails.  I can only see 2 possible errors,  either you're making a mistake in the syntax, or one of your types is in two different namespaces (i.e. even with using you are still getting a type name clash).

Comment: See answer - something else to try - just to be 100% sure it's not declared elsewhere.  As otherwise I'm stumped.

Comment: This is going to work, but to use SAPTEST foreach type of that namespace, snd this of course is not the solution because using directive should resolve it.

Comment: If the SAPTEST example works then I believe you must have IDestinationConfiguration defined in another namespace.  It doesn't make sense otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too and couldn't figure it out until I finally found the answer on a post at http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1876430, the last line which said:

"Also, make sure your target framework is ".NET v4.0" NOT ".NET v4.0 Client" -- that way you get the System.Web namespace that is required."

My project was targeting 4.0 client target framework. Once I changed it to just .NET Freamework 4.0, all the references worked as expected.